# משנה תענית ד ג - was דילוג necessary on days 3 and on?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, mishna

The משנה תענית ד ג says

> וְאַנְשֵׁי הַמַּעֲמָד ... בַּיּוֹם הָרִאשׁוֹן, בְּרֵאשִׁית, וִיְהִי
> רָקִיעַ. בַּשֵּׁנִי, יְהִי רָקִיעַ, וְיִקָּווּ הַמַּיִם.
> בַּשְּׁלִישִׁי, יִקָּווּ הַמַּיִם, וִיְהִי מְאֹרֹת. בָּרְבִיעִי, יְהִי
> מְאֹרֹת, וְיִשְׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם. בַּחֲמִישִׁי, יִשְׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם,
> וְתּוֹצֵא הָאָרֶץ. בַּשִּׁשִּׁי, תּוֹצֵא הָאָרֶץ, וַיְכֻלּוּ
> הַשָּׁמַיִם. פָּרָשָׁה גְדוֹלָה, קוֹרִין אוֹתָהּ בִּשְׁנַיִם,
> וְהַקְּטַנָּה בְּיָחִיד, ...

The רע"ב explains according to רב's explanation from the גמרא כז:, that on Sunday, בראשית has 5 פסוקים, so ראשון got 1-3, שני got 3-5 (repeating 3), and שלישי got יהי רקיע - 6-8.
Similarly, on Monday, ראשון got 6-8, שני got 9-11, and שלישי got 11-13 (repeating 11).

He then says "וכן כולם" - which I think means that this procedure is followed the rest of the weekdays as well. תוי"ט uses that phrase as well.

But then I checked the other days of the week - they all have at least one day with 6 פסוקים - e.g. on Tuesday, we would יקוו המים (5) and יהי מארת (6) - so we could just give ראשון 9-13, שני 14-16 and שלישי 17-19 - what דילוג is needed the rest of the days?

Comment: Maybe the וכן כולם just means that on the other days the smaller parsha was read by one, and the larger by two, without there being a need for דילוג